how do I create a TEXTSPLIT skill in a cognitive search and how do I reference it in an indexer
I don`t know how to create a text split skill and reference it in an indexer
I created an indexer after importing my data, and I used built-in skills such as Language detection and Keyphase extraction. However, I can't find a way to add a TEXTSPLIT skill to the indexer I created.
index:
{
  "@odata.context": "https://mssearchser.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexes/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC690C7EB356B6\"",
  "name": "azureblob-index",
  "defaultScoringProfile": "",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "content",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_content_type",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_size",
      "type": "Edm.Int64",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_last_modified",
      "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_content_md5",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_name",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_path",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": true,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_file_extension",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_content_type",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_author",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": true,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_creation_date",
      "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_last_modified",
      "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "locations",
      "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "keyphrases",
      "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "language",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "merged_content",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "text",
      "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "layoutText",
      "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    }
  ],
  "scoringProfiles": [],
  "corsOptions": null,
  "suggesters": [],
  "analyzers": [],
  "normalizers": [],
  "tokenizers": [],
  "tokenFilters": [],
  "charFilters": [],
  "encryptionKey": null,
  "similarity": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity",
    "k1": null,
    "b": null
  },
  "semantic": null,
  "vectorSearch": null
}

indexer:
{
  "@odata.context": "https://mssearchser.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC690CB8941711\"",
  "name": "terminal-indexer",
  "description": "",
  "dataSourceName": "terminal-data",
  "skillsetName": "terminal-skillset",
  "targetIndexName": "azureblob-index",
  "disabled": null,
  "schedule": null,
  "parameters": {
    "batchSize": null,
    "maxFailedItems": 0,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": 0,
    "base64EncodeKeys": null,
    "configuration": {
      "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
      "parsingMode": "default",
      "imageAction": "generateNormalizedImages"
    }
  },
  "fieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "targetFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "mappingFunction": {
        "name": "base64Encode",
        "parameters": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputFieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content/locations",
      "targetFieldName": "locations"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content/keyphrases",
      "targetFieldName": "keyphrases"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/language",
      "targetFieldName": "language"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content",
      "targetFieldName": "merged_content"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/normalized_images/*/text",
      "targetFieldName": "text"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/normalized_images/*/layoutText",
      "targetFieldName": "layoutText"
    }
  ],
  "cache": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}


please share Indexes,Indexers, and please share the data you have sent to  Indexers

I am unable to attach the dataset and I cant write all the indexes here, it says the character is too long. what do you suggest I do to be able to upload my data

please add in the above question

I have added the index and indexer.json


The Text Split skill is designed to segment text into manageable chunks, either by sentences or pages of specified lengths.
It offers several parameters for customization, such as determining the mode of splitting (pages or sentences) and setting the maximum length of each page.

Sample Definition:
{
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
    "textSplitMode" : "pages", 
    "maximumPageLength": 1000,
    "pageOverlapLength": 100,
    "maximumPagesToTake": 1,
    "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "text",
            "source": "/document/content"
        },
        {
            "name": "languageCode",
            "source": "/document/language"
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "textItems",
            "targetName": "mypages"
        }
    ]
}





Additionally, parameters like page overlap length and maximum pages to take enable finer control over the splitting process, particularly useful for scenarios like data chunking and vectorization.

Sample Input:
{
    "values": [
        {
            "recordId": "1",
            "data": {
                "text": "This is the loan application for Joe Romero...",
                "languageCode": "en"
            }
        },
        {
            "recordId": "2",
            "data": {
                "text": "This is the second document...",
                "languageCode": "en"
            }
        }
    ]
}



Language support is provided through the defaultLanguageCode parameter, ensuring accurate splitting, especially for languages with different sentence structures.
The skill takes text inputs along with optional language codes and outputs an array of substrings, facilitating downstream processing.

Sample Output:
{
    "values": [
        {
            "recordId": "1",
            "data": {
                "textItems": [
                    "This is the loan...Here is the overlap part",
                    "Here is the overlap part...In the next section, we continue..."
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "recordId": "2",
            "data": {
                "textItems": [
                    "This is the second document...Here is the overlap part...",
                    "Here is the overlap part...In the next section of the second doc..."
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}





The Text Split skill enhances text processing workflows by breaking down lengthy texts into more manageable units, improving efficiency and accuracy in subsequent tasks such as analysis or translation.

For Skillset your data:
Note: change the source according to the data you sent
{
  "@odata.context": "https://[your-search-service].search.windows.net/$metadata#skillsets/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC690CB8941711\"",
  "name": "terminal-skillset1",
  "description": "",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
      "textSplitMode": "pages",
      "maximumPageLength": 1000,
      "pageOverlapLength": 100,
      "maximumPagesToTake": 1,
      "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/merged_content"
        },
        {
          "name": "languageCode",
          "source": "/document/language"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "textItems",
          "targetName": "mypages"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}



change Skillset in the Indexer:
change the sourceFieldName and `targetFieldName according   to the fields

{
  "@odata.context": "https://mssearchser.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC690CB8941711\"",
  "name": "terminal-indexer1",
  "description": "",
  "dataSourceName": "terminal-data",
  "skillsetName": "terminal-skillset", // Reference your skillset here
  "targetIndexName": "azureblob-index",
  "disabled": null,
  "schedule": null,
  "parameters": {
    "batchSize": null,
    "maxFailedItems": 0,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": 0,
    "base64EncodeKeys": null,
    "configuration": {
      "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
      "parsingMode": "default",
      "imageAction": "generateNormalizedImages"
    }
  },
  "fieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "targetFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "mappingFunction": {
        "name": "base64Encode",
        "parameters": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputFieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content/locations",
      "targetFieldName": "locations"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content/keyphrases",
      "targetFieldName": "keyphrases"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/language",
      "targetFieldName": "language"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content",
      "targetFieldName": "merged_content"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/normalized_images/*/text",
      "targetFieldName": "text"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/normalized_images/*/layoutText",
      "targetFieldName": "layoutText"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/mypages/*", // Reference the output field from the skillset
      "targetFieldName": "textItems" // Map to your desired field
    }
  ],
  "cache": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}


Yh, it worked. I was able to reference a skillset in an indexer. However, the splitText feature empty. what can I do about this?
'
"text":[has loads on words in this]
"splitText": [],
"layoutText": [has loads on words in this]
'
